# status code 405 issue..Alamofire POST request...

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire, http-status-code-405

I am trying to make a Alamofire POST request. This is how I am making the request..

```
     Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers : headers)
        .responseString { response in
            print(response.result)
 }
```

Though I am getting the result as 'SUCCESS', the status code is always shown as 405 while it should have been 200. In the 'encoding' part of the request, I have tried everything like JSONEncoding.default,JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, URLEncoding.httpbody...but always the status code is still 405. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: i provide answer for your problem it's may be backend issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution for this issue...A couple of changes had to be made..

The header which was given was this: let headers = [ "Content-Type" : "application/json"]. But it had to be let headers = [ "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]. 
         Also the encoding should be given as URLEncoding.httpBody.

Making these changes made it work fine...

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with your server because this status code only comes when server disable the api

> The HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that
>   the request method is known by the server but has been disabled and
>   cannot be used. The two mandatory methods, GET and HEAD, must never be
>   disabled and should not return this error code.

So Contact your server(backend developer), make sure your url is correct

Comment: i pretty sure about that your url is posted wrong from mobile side append url with "/" at the end of url and try again

Comment: then there is only one choice please post your url and params

Comment: The url works fine in postman without the "/". But if it is not appended with "/" in the code, then it gives a status code of 500 instead of 405..

Comment: can you update the `URL` in your OP? because that's the only helpful clue to find your issue and get it resolved! @Jaydeep is right though.

Comment: yes i check your url in my project and give the reason what is problem

Comment: Ok...this is the url -> http://osho.binaryic.com/v1/feedback . And the parameters are name, email, phone_no, feedback. All the parameters are of string type...

Comment: also provide parameters

Comment: it requires ssl certificate

Comment: ok...so can you please help me with what needs to be done to have the ssl certificate...?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem. The API endpoint worked fine with Android Retrofit, also tested with PostMan. Also the header's Content-Type was application/json.
It was really strange bug. I've used Fiddler to check the response.
The error message was

> The requested resource does not support http method 'T'/'ST'.

I used GET/POST method, but it said I was using the T/ST, instead of GET/POST

I found answer from the Alamofire's issues.

When I called the API endpoint without parameters, I used the blank dictionary as parameter.

> Alamofire.request("URL",
>       method: .get,
>       parameters: [:],
>       encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: completionHandler)

I changed it to nil

> Alamofire.request("URL",
>       method: .get,
>       parameters: nil,
>       encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: completionHandler)

After that, it worked fine.
Hope it will help you. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace:

`responseString` with  `responseJSON`
AND `URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)` with `URLEncoding.default`

LIKE:

```
Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in 

//Do something

}
```

Comment: try to print `responseObject.result.value` in my function. I have tested this function more than 100 times.

Comment: printing responseObject.result.value gives 'nil'. Just FYI..the url works fine in Postman..